# How to update records Dynamically through Inline editing in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hello I want to edit my records in list view itself rather than open a new page to edit a single record. The Problem i am facing is i can edit the records by inline editing but the records dont get updated maybe the issue is with the ajax function i am using please help me solve this bug The Below Is My Code :

The Controller :

```
public function updateDb()
      {
             $column = $this->input->post('column');
             $editval = $this->input->post('editval');
             $id = $this->input->post('id');

             //$this->load->model('user_m');                     
             $this->user_m->inline( $column, $editval, $id );

             return;
      }
```

The Model Code :

```
public function inline( $column, $editval, $id )
        {
            $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users set $column = $editval WHERE  id=$id");
        }
```

The View Code :

```
<td class="success"  contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase"><?php echo $user->sip_id; ?></td>
```

the Ajax Function :

```
    <script>


    function showEdit(editableObj) {
        $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
    } 



    function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
        $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(<?php echo site_url('img/loaderIcon.gif');?>loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo current_url('/admin/user/updateDb')?>",
            type: "POST",
            data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
            success: function(data){
                $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
            }        
       });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is column, editableObj and id values? Did't see its passed

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali In model and controller?

Comment: in html element `onBlur="saveToDatabase"`

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali  i did not understand! what i shoud be doing here?

Comment: should passed parameter with values when blur event detected like so : `onBlur="saveToDatabase(this, 'column_name','id')"`

Comment: Thanks man :) @NorlihazmeyGhazali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<script>


    function showEdit(editableObj) {
        $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
    } 


        function save(editableObj,column,id) {

        $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(<?php echo site_url('img/loaderIcon.gif');?>loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
        $.ajax({

            url: "<?php echo base_url()?>admin/user/updateDb",
            type: "POST",
            data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
            success: function(data){
                $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
            }  

        });
    }

    </script>
```